# Slow loading ImageView in ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, imageview, picasso, firebase-storage

I have read some posts about loading image in Android but this argument is a bit confusing for me yet.
I have a ListView and I would load inside it some images from firebase storage. I have also other images from https://books.google, these images are loaded immediately.

When I load images from firebase storage the device is very slow. I have tried using *Picasso* library and also with this code:

```
 public class loadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader reader;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }


            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) url.getContent());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bookImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Maybe Volley is better than Picasso? Or Fresco or Glide?
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hey use **https://github.com/thest1/LazyList**. This library downloads your listview images in the background without affecting the listview scrolling.

Comment: just serach "ImageLoader" on google you will found many solutions

Comment: I have found the solution: GLIDE. It is better than Picasso and it is recommended by Google. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Carlo You can post and accept your own answer for this question to be properly tagged. :)

Comment: thanks @AL. I will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution: **GLIDE**. It is better than **Picasso** and it is recommended by Google. 
With this link you can have some informations about the difference from Glide and Picasso:

[Glide vs Picasso](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

Good Job.